What part of linguistics is "number two" in the sentence "i have number two"?
What part of linguistics is "number two" in the sentence "i have number two"?. Let's split it and discuss it into "number" and "two"
Is "two" an adjunct, modifier, or complement of "number"?. Or "number" is a noun adjunct of "two"?. Or "number two" is a phrase? But a phrase must have a modifier(pre-modifier / post-modifier), so which is the modifier?

I'd say it's an adjectival phrase modifying a context-dependent noun that's not explicitly specified - perhaps [numbered] menu item or similar. Where within that adjectival phrase, the word number is itself noun adjectivally modified by two. But I'm not sure how such categorization helps you learn English.
